# how to make frontend api authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-passport

I have created an API Authentication system in Laravel using passport package. when a user log in every time create a personal access token and when logout token is revoked. I have tested it in `Postman`. but when I try to this from frontend I can't manage the personal access token for every request and response. now, I want to know How can i manage the `Personal Access Token` from frontend and add the token for every request an upcoming request.

Here is my code sample.

```
public $successStatus = 200;
public function login()
{ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus); 

    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below headers for every request

```php
[
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
]
```

For more information, refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#passing-the-access-token)